# Mac pop up notifications getting cut off on the right

Tags: macos, mac, display, notifications

Recently all of my pop up notifications are getting cut off so I can only see half of it, like the computer thinks my screen is wider than it is, as you can see in the picture:

[image]

I have a 2019 15 inch MacBook Pro, with Mojave 10.14.6.
I also have a monitor attached which is a LEN P27u-10 Display but this issue still persists even if I detach the monitor.

Comment: Pure guess - try changing monitor resolution temporarily, maybe also reboot after you change it. Leave the external disconnected whilst testing.

Comment: @Tetsujin Your suggestion worked, thank you!

Comment: Sometimes the old "switch it off then back on again" really works! I'll drop in a quick answer. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments… based on nothing but guesswork, try the old "switch it off then on again" with a slight twist.

Try changing monitor resolution temporarily, maybe also reboot after you change it. Leave the external disconnected whilst testing.

Comment: Ah.... the old "on and off with a twist' method! :-)

Answer (score 1):

if you're connected to an external monitor, go to displays in the setting menu and click the arrangement tab. Once in your arrangement tab; drag the white bar from your mac to the external monitor screen. then move it back to your mac. it fixes the mac trying to decide the width of the screen. I run into this bug every so often. The white bar indicates which monitor to display the notifications and it's defaulted to your mac. This accomplishes what turning it on and off again would do without actually turning it off and on again